# How do I show progress in status/task bar button using Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, progress-bar, delphi-7

If you copy files under Windows 7, you will see the **progress** of the copy in a sort of **progress bar begin displayed in the status or task bar button** of the application.

Can this be achieved using Delphi 7 ?

I have some lengthy operation which would be ideally suited to show it's progress this way.

**sample of such a button using copy with Total Commander**

[image: sample of such a button using copy with Total Commander].

Comment: In the newer Delphi's you can just use the builtin `TTaskBar` component, see: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Taskbar.TTaskbar

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`ITaskbarList3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391692.aspx) interface for that, specifically its [`SetProgressState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391697.aspx) and [`SetProgressValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391698.aspx) methods.  Use `CoCreateInstance()` specifying `CLSID_TaskbarList` and `IID_ITaskbarList3` to access the interface.

For example:

```
type
  ITaskbarList = interface(IUnknown) 
    ['{56FDF342-FD6D-11D0-958A-006097C9A090}']
    function HrInit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function AddTab(hwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DeleteTab(hwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ActivateTab(hwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetActiveAlt(hwnd: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  ITaskbarList2 = interface(ITaskbarList) 
    ['{602D4995-B13A-429B-A66E-1935E44F4317}']
    function MarkFullscreenWindow(hwnd: HWND; 
      fFullscreen: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  THUMBBUTTON = record 
    dwMask: DWORD;
    iId: UINT;
    iBitmap: UINT;
    hIcon: HICON;
    szTip: packed array[0..259] of WCHAR;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
  end;
  TThumbButton = THUMBBUTTON;
  PThumbButton = ^TThumbButton;

  ITaskbarList3 = interface(ITaskbarList2) 
    ['{EA1AFB91-9E28-4B86-90E9-9E9F8A5EEFAF}']
    function SetProgressValue(hwnd: HWND; ullCompleted: ULONGLONG; 
      ullTotal: ULONGLONG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetProgressState(hwnd: HWND; 
      tbpFlags: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function RegisterTab(hwndTab: HWND; hwndMDI: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UnregisterTab(hwndTab: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetTabOrder(hwndTab: HWND; 
      hwndInsertBefore: HWND): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetTabActive(hwndTab: HWND; hwndMDI: HWND; 
      tbatFlags: Integer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ThumbBarAddButtons(hwnd: HWND; cButtons: UINT;
      pButton: PThumbButton): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ThumbBarUpdateButtons(hwnd: HWND; cButtons: UINT;
      pButton: PThumbButton): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ThumbBarSetImageList(hwnd: HWND; 
      himl: HIMAGELIST): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetOverlayIcon(hwnd: HWND; hIcon: HICON; 
      pszDescription: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetThumbnailTooltip(hwnd: HWND; 
      pszTip: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetThumbnailClip(hwnd: HWND; 
      var prcClip: TRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

const
  CLSID_TaskbarList: TGUID = '{56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090}';
  TBPF_NOPROGRESS    = 0; 
  TBPF_INDETERMINATE = $1; 
  TBPF_NORMAL        = $2; 
  TBPF_ERROR         = $4; 
  TBPF_PAUSED        = $8; 

var
  TBL: ITaskbarList3;
  I: Integer;
begin
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC, ITaskbarList3, TBL);

  if (TBL <> nil) then 
    TBL.SetProgressState(Application.Handle, TBPF_INDETERMINATE);
  try
    for I := 0 to 100 do
    begin
      if (TBL <> nil) then 
        TBL.SetProgressValue(Application.Handle, I, 100);
      Sleep(1000);
    end;
  finally
    if (TBL <> nil) then 
      TBL.SetProgressState(Application.Handle, TBPF_NOPROGRESS);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Much appreciated. I will try this out today and let the results be known.

Comment: This code works. Sorry for the delay, took me some time to find the time to work on the code where I needed this, but this works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

There are some complete solutions like [TaskBarList](https://github.com/chaosben/theunknownones/tree/master/Components/TaskBarList) component.

`TTaskbarListProgress` is a Pascal wrapper class for displaying progress in the taskbar.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can try my unit (Tested in Delphi 7):

```
{*******************************************************************************

                      Windows 7 TaskBar Progress Unit File

                           File Version: 0.0.0.3

                       https://github.com/tarampampam

*******************************************************************************}


unit Win7TaskBarProgressUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX;

type
  ITaskbarList = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{56FDF342-FD6D-11D0-958A-006097C9A090}']
    function HrInit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function AddTab(hwnd: LongWord): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DeleteTab(hwnd: LongWord): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ActivateTab(hwnd: LongWord): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetActiveAlt(hwnd: LongWord): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  ITaskbarList2 = interface(ITaskbarList)
    ['{602D4995-B13A-429B-A66E-1935E44F4317}']
    function MarkFullscreenWindow(hwnd: LongWord;
      fFullscreen: LongBool): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  ITaskbarList3 = interface(ITaskbarList2)
    ['{EA1AFB91-9E28-4B86-90E9-9E9F8A5EEFAF}']
    procedure SetProgressValue(hwnd: LongWord; ullCompleted: UInt64; ullTotal: UInt64); stdcall;
    procedure SetProgressState(hwnd: LongWord; tbpFlags: Integer); stdcall;
  end;

type
  TTaskBarProgressStyle = (tbpsNone, tbpsIndeterminate, tbpsNormal, tbpsError, tbpsPaused);

  TWin7TaskProgressBar = class
    glHandle: LongWord;
    glMin: Byte;
    glMax,
    glValue: Integer;
    glStyle: TTaskBarProgressStyle;
    glVisible,
    glMarquee: Boolean;
    glTaskBarInterface: ITaskbarList3;
  private
    procedure SetProgress(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetMax(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetStyle(const Style: TTaskBarProgressStyle);
    procedure SetVisible(const IsVisible: Boolean);
    procedure SetMarquee(const IsMarquee: Boolean);
  published
    constructor Create(const Handle: LongWord);
    property Max: Integer read glMax write SetMax default 100;
    property Min: Byte read glMin default 0;
    property Progress: Integer read glValue write SetProgress default 0;
    property Marquee: Boolean read glMarquee write SetMarquee default False;
    property Style: TTaskBarProgressStyle read glStyle write SetStyle default tbpsNone;
    property Visible: Boolean read glVisible write SetVisible default False;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TWin7TaskProgressBar.SetMax(const Value: Integer);
begin
  glMax := Value;
  SetProgress(glValue);
end;

procedure TWin7TaskProgressBar.SetProgress(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if (glTaskBarInterface <> nil) and (glHandle <> 0) then begin
    glValue := Value;
    if not glMarquee then
      glTaskBarInterface.SetProgressValue(glHandle, UInt64(glValue), UInt64(glMax));
  end;
end;

procedure TWin7TaskProgressBar.SetStyle(const Style: TTaskBarProgressStyle);
const
  Flags: array[TTaskBarProgressStyle] of Cardinal = (0, 1, 2, 4, 8);
begin
  if (glTaskBarInterface <> nil) and (glHandle <> 0) then
    glTaskBarInterface.SetProgressState(glHandle, Flags[Style]);

  glStyle := Style;
end;

procedure TWin7TaskProgressBar.SetVisible(const IsVisible: Boolean);
begin
  if IsVisible then begin
    if (glStyle <> tbpsNormal) then
      SetStyle(tbpsNormal)
  end else
    SetStyle(tbpsNone);

  glVisible := IsVisible;
end;

procedure TWin7TaskProgressBar.SetMarquee(const IsMarquee: Boolean);
begin
  if IsMarquee then
    SetStyle(tbpsIndeterminate)
  else begin
    SetStyle(tbpsNone);
    if glVisible then begin
      SetProgress(glValue);
      SetStyle(tbpsNormal);
    end;
  end;

  glMarquee := IsMarquee;
end;

constructor TWin7TaskProgressBar.Create(const Handle: LongWord);
const
  CLSID_TaskbarList: TGUID = '{56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090}';
var
  OSVersionInfo : TOSVersionInfo;
begin
  OSVersionInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize := sizeof(TOSVersionInfo);
  if (Handle <> 0) and GetVersionEx(OSVersionInfo) then
    if OSVersionInfo.dwMajorVersion >= 6 then try
      glHandle := Handle;
      CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC, ITaskbarList3, glTaskBarInterface);

      if (glTaskBarInterface <> nil) then
        glTaskBarInterface.SetProgressState(glHandle, 0);

      glMin := 0;
      glMax := 100;
      glValue := 10;
      glStyle := tbpsNormal;

      SetStyle(glStyle);
      SetVisible(glVisible);
    except
      glTaskBarInterface := nil;
    end;
end;


destructor TWin7TaskProgressBar.Destroy;
begin
  if (glTaskBarInterface <> nil) then begin
    glTaskBarInterface.SetProgressState(glHandle, 0);
    glTaskBarInterface := nil;
  end;
end;

end.
```