# How to get application's Windows taskbar button to show progress of progress bar

Tags: windows, delphi, progress-bar, delphi-xe, taskbar

One of the features introduced in Windows 7 (or was it Vista?) is the capability of the taskbar button of an application to show the progress of a progress bar in that application. When I create a form and place a progress bar on it, it doesn't show up in the taskbar button, so I assume this isn't done automatically. How can I get Windows 7 to show the progress of a progress bar on the application's taskbar button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show progress in status/task bar button using Delphi 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814765/how-do-i-show-progress-in-status-task-bar-button-using-delphi-7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be easily accomplished using the [ITaskList3 COM Interface.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391692%28VS.85%29.aspx)

For using it in Delphi check the following link:
[Fun with the Windows 7 Taskbar](http://www.drbob42.com/examine/examinC5.htm)

Also Check this link for complete article describing the features provided by ITaskList3 
[Windows 7: How to display progress bar on taskbar icon?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80082/Windows-7-How-to-display-progress-bar-on-taskbar-i)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use TTaskbarListProgress component from the [TaskbarListComponents](http://code.google.com/p/theunknownones/wiki/TaskbarListComponents) open sourced component pack. Released under the [dwywbdbu](http://code.google.com/p/theunknownones/source/browse/dwywbdbu_license.txt) license.