# How to set the taskbar's progress indicator?

Tags: delphi, taskbar, delphi-xe7

While performing long operations, some applications shows a progressbar behind the application icon, in the taskbar.

[image: Screenshot of a taskbar with a progress bar in one of the buttons.]

...

[image: Screenshot of a taskbar with a progress bar in one of the buttons.]

How can this progress indicator be set from a Delphi application?

Comment: When you add an image to your Q, please replace the "enter image description here" placeholder with an informative description of the image (like "Screenshot of a taskbar with a progress bar in one of the buttons"). A visually impaired user, who uses a screen reader, will find that text much more helpful. Also, search engines like Google will do a much better job understanding the image.

Comment: That's the task *button*, not bar. The bar holds all buttons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5816222/4299358 also applies - didn't that turn up in your search results?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633389/how-to-get-applications-windows-taskbar-button-to-show-progress-of-progress-bar?rq=1 (in the "Related" panel to the right).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: thanks for suggestion, I will set an image description next time

Comment: Very strange, both questions wasn't in the "Similar questions" box

Comment: Not so strange, SO's internal search tends to be pretty weak at finding similar questions. It's important that you do thorough research before you post here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In modern Delphi versions, you have the `TTaskbar` component in the `Win32` part of the component palette.

Drop that one on your form, set `ProgressState` (to `Normal`, say), `ProgressMaxValue` (to `100`, say), and `ProgressValue` (to `50`, say).

In my experience, this component is buggy -- or at least it has been in earlier versions. So be careful.

A safer alternative, of course, is to use the Win32 API directly. See the official documentation for [`ITaskbarList3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist3).

Comment: "*In my experience, this component is buggy -- or at least it has been in earlier versions*" - it still is

Comment: Yes. Buggy. FastMM reports a memory leak after using that control.

Comment: Seems to be working alright in Delphi 11. FastMM doesn't report memory leaks either.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example ([link](https://fsoriano.developpez.com/articles/windows7/delphi/utilisez-barre-taches-windows-7-dans-vos-applications-delphi-2010/)):

```
unit uMainTest;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ObjectArray, ShlObj, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, ActiveX, ComObj,
  ImgList, CommCtrl, PropSys;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    Button2: TButton;
    trackBar: TTrackBar;
    GroupBox5: TGroupBox;
    chkState1: TCheckBox;
    chkState2: TCheckBox;
    chkState3: TCheckBox;
    chkState4: TCheckBox;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btProgressBarDemoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btProgressStateClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure trackBarChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btConfigureTasksClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    TaskBar: ITaskBarList3;
    msgTaskbarButtonCreated: cardinal;

  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public

  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

uses Registry, ShellApi, uFileRegistration ;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.btProgressBarDemoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TaskBar.SetProgressValue(Handle, trackBar.Position, trackBar.Max);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btProgressStateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Flags: integer;
begin
  Flags := TBPF_NOPROGRESS;
  if chkState1.Checked then
    Flags := Flags or chkState1.Tag;
  if chkState2.Checked then
    Flags := Flags or chkState2.Tag;
  if chkState3.Checked then
    Flags := Flags or chkState3.Tag;
  if chkState4.Checked then
    Flags := Flags or chkState4.Tag;
  TaskBar.SetProgressState(Handle, Flags);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btConfigureTasksClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  JumpList: ICustomDestinationList;
  RemovedDestination: IObjectArray;
  TaskList: IObjectCollection;
  pcMaxSlots: cardinal;
  Link1: IShellLink;
begin
  JumpList := CreateComObject(CLSID_DestinationList) as ICustomDestinationList;
  OleCheck(JumpList.BeginList(pcMaxSlots, IID_IObjectArray,
    RemovedDestination));
  try

    // A présent, on prépare une nouvelle liste de tâches à ajouter dans la
    // JumpList.
    TaskList := CreateComObject(CLSID_EnumerableObjectCollection)
      as IObjectCollection;

    // Enfin, on définit la liste des tâches en appelant AddUserTasks.
    OleCheck(JumpList.AddUserTasks(TaskList));
  except
    // En cas d'erreur, il faut annuler la liste en cours de définition
    JumpList.AbortList;
    raise; // Puis on redéclenche l'exception.
  end;
  OleCheck(JumpList.CommitList);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  msgTaskbarButtonCreated := RegisterWindowMessage('TaskbarButtonCreated');

  OleCheck(SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID('Dvp.Delphi.DemoTaskbar.1'));
end;

procedure TfrmMain.trackBarChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TaskBar.SetProgressValue(Handle, trackBar.Position, trackBar.Max);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = msgTaskbarButtonCreated then
    TaskBar := CreateComObject(CLSID_TaskbarList) as ITaskBarList3
  else
    inherited WndProc(Message);
end;

end.
```